# preg_match(_all) with a rule for every space character

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a way of making sure that every space has at least three characters (a-zA-Z and single quotes are allowed) on each side of it. It does exactly that, however only with the first space. Not the rest of them. I tried `preg_match_all()` to no avail, hence my question/post to you guys.

```
<?PHP
  function validateSpaces($str) {
    if ( strpos( $str, ' ' ) !== FALSE && !preg_match( '/(([a-z\']{3,})([ ]{1})([a-z\']{3,}))/i', $str ) )
      return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
  }

  echo validateSpaces( 'Hey There' ); // Valid (correct)
  echo validateSpaces( 'He There' ); // Invalid (correct)
  echo validateSpaces( 'Hey Ther e' ); // Valid (incorrect)
?>
```

As you can see, the first two examples are working like they should, but the second one validates although the second space only has one character on the right side of it. Which is not what I want.

Any help or attempt to help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance,
Chris.

Comment: Might also mention that regular expression is not one of my strong suits.

Comment: Mine neither. This tool is awesome, though. http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: I believe you're looking for a positive look-ahead in the scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last modification, will macth only if we have ony one space (trim string before trying to match it):

```
^([a-z']{3,} ?)+$
```

Comment: This allows me to have several spaces next to each other, and does not solve the initial issue. Thank you though!

Comment: just add one or more spaces I will modify example above

Comment: @MatejB: yes, with trim, it will work, might include it in the answer too.

Comment: Yeah. This is definitely what I wanted. Thanks a lot @MatejB!

Comment: You don't have to use trim; just put `(?<! )` right before the `$`. Or you could change it to `^([a-z']{3,}[ $])+`, I think that would work.

Answer (score 2):

You could explode the string on spaces and check the array's contents.

Not complete solution:

```
$temb=explode(' ', $str);
$valid=true;
foreach ($temb as $tt) {
  if (strlen($tt)<3 || !{a preg_match for the right characters in $tt}) {
    $valid=false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: If string is big this will be a big loop!

Comment: I agree with MatejB. In this certain case it is not however, but I would still prefer a regex solution (if there is one).

Comment: @Chris: that is right. It can be still optimized (do the preg_match for the characters after the loop if it is still valid, etc), I just gave an idea. Mark's solution seems to be great, but I have no votes left for today :).

Comment: Instead of the loop, you could also make use of `array_filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_match_all()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) rather than [preg_match()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), and compare the number of results with a substr_count($str,' ') to see that **every** space matches your regexp criteria

Comment: "The number of results" - I can only assume that you are talking about the $matches variable. If that is the case indeed, it returns more result entries then it should to simply count it and compare towards the substr_count result. Thank you though.

Comment: @Chris: you could easily rewrite that regex with the right capturing groups, and then this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

How about this - you could combine the patterns into one if performance is an issue; I find more than one level of conditional logic difficult to read:

```
function validate( $value )
{
  $ptn_a = '/(^| )[A-Za-z\']{0,2} /';
  $ptn_b = '/ [A-Za-z\']{0,2}($| )/';

  if ( preg_match( $ptn_a, $value ) )
    return false;

  if ( preg_match( $ptn_b, $value ) )
    return false;

  return true;
}

var_dump( validate('Hey There') );
var_dump( validate('He There') );
var_dump( validate('Hey Ther e') );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate($string = '')


{


  $regexp = '/([^\w]|^)([\w]{1,2})([^\w]|$)/';

  if (strlen(trim($string)) && !preg_match($regexp, $string)) {
      return 'TRUE';
  }

  return 'FALSE';


}


print validate('   ');
print "\n";
print validate('Hey There');
print "\n";
print validate('He There');
print "\n";
print validate('Hey  ');
print "\n";
print validate('Hey Ther e');
print "\n";
print validate('Hey Th ere');
```

This can also help.